# generate json with backslash using jackson

Tags: json, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka, jackson-databind

.
I am using Jackson library to generate json. Jackson is generating the json in below format.

```
{"color":"yellow","type":"renault"}
```

I want to generate the above format with backslash as below:

`{\"color\":\"yellow\",\"type\":\"renault\"}`

The format with the backslash is required as I am doing transformation using kafka stream API.

Here is my model Class:

```
public class Car {

    private String color;
    private String type;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(final String color, final String type) {
        this.color = color;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(final String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Please do let me know what configuration/property change do I need to do in order to generate the json in the above required format.

I have also attached the screenshot to show rest of my code.

Thanks in advance!

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p0S9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonStringEncoder.

Here is the sample code:

JsonStringEncoder e = JsonStringEncoder.getInstance();
        String jsonString = new String(e.quoteAsString(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(car)));